AMD drivers on Linux
Why is it that everywhere I look I seem to find, "You don't need drivers on Linux; they're already built into the kernel" as if I have a need for a proprietary driver that goes black screen when I open graphics intensive programs instead of a real answer as to what command to use or why there's no directory for such and such?
~How do I install AMD drivers on Ubuntu L.T.S.? ~

You do know drivers are kernel modules; thus the connection with the kernel, and you've not told us what Ubuntu product/release you're asking about; as Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice with the default set by install media; so which release are you using & which kernel stack?  If you need help with a specific release, provide details (inc. product & release; eg. Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.5 LTS or Ubuntu Server 22.04.5 LTS as both Server & Desktop have different kernel stack defaults; HWE/GA), plus of your details hardware (Most AMD drivers are already in the kernel as open source)

first you need to check if your graphics card is correctly detected and if the drivers are running normally on your system. To do this you can use these commands:
lspci -v | grep -i vga 

This will display the device that has been identified as a graphics card by the system
lspci -k | grep -A 3 -i vga 

This will display the graphics card and the loaded drivers for it.
Now in case the commands show you that your graphics card is not working you can visit the official AMD website
https://www.amd.com/en/support/download/drivers.html
search for your hardware, download and install the Debian package using the following command
sudo dpkg -i amdgpu-driver.deb

if the drivers still do not work, you always try to change the Kernel version by following this guide:
https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-change-default-kernel-in-ubuntu-22-04-20-04-lts/
I hope this helps your issue.

Go to https://www.amd.com/en/support/download/linux-drivers.html, select Ubuntu x86 64-bit and select your Ubuntu version. Then you can install it with the command sudo dpkg -i driver.deb
Hope this helps! :)
